# Google Maps (custom) + embedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, embedly

I would like to be able to control the look & feel of the google map that embedly embeds. In particular, I'd like to be able to use the "disableDefaultUI" option as outlined by Google at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-disableUI.

It doesn't appear to be possible to control this from the URL params that google use. Is it possible for me to be able to pass these parameters to embedly? Or any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, not at this time. You would have to use the google maps api directly for something like this.